# How the system know the end of data segment

Tags: c, assembly, memory, heap-memory, sbrk

### 2 Questions (the same topic) :

Some examples :

Let's say i have something like that in **assembly** (GCC Compilation) :

```
movl 12 -4(%rbp)
```

When i will give the adress **-4(%rbp)** to another instruction, how the system will **know where stop** ? Because **-4(%rbp)** is the starting adress but we don't have any informations about the stop, it could be a **2x2bytes** instead of 4bytes.

My 2nd question is kinda the same, but **with the heap**, considering i'm using [sbrk](http://manpagesfr.free.fr/man/man2/brk.2.html) :

When i'll call `sbrk(0)` it will give the adress of the **break** in the heap.
Let's say i'm using `sbrk(20)`and then `sbrk(40)` the break will be moved, now i'm trying to access to the space allocated by `sbrk(20)`, same as the assembly, how the system will know when stop and not overflow on the `sbrk(40)` space ?

Maybe it's a little confusing, tell me if you want me to develop more.

Comment: The size of the datum an address refers to is either known from the context (e.g. if you pass the address of an integer to a function, the function knows that an integer is always four bytes) or you have to pass the size with the address. As with many things, this becomes more and more obvious with increasing experience.

Comment: Please one question at a time.

Comment: 2nd question: the system won't know anything. it if overflows it overflows.

Comment: What's the difference between _2x2bytes_ and _4bytes_?

Comment: Thanks ! Got my answers

Comment: Every instruction has an operand-size which you (as the asm programmer) choose.  That implies the size of the memory operand.  It's up to you not to touch unmapped memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'l' of movl means long(32 bit integer, 64 bit float).
The last letter defines the size(in gas syntax). 
Wiki: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/GAS_Syntax